# How to use shard key in update queries generated by SimpleMongoRepository

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

We are using Spring Data MongoDB to connect to an Azure CosmosDB instance that is sharded. We currently face the issue, that the default SimpleMongoRepository implementation does not seem to support specifying a shard key that is then used in the query section of the update command sent to the MongoDB (or CosmosDB in our case). Compared to MongoDB, CosmosDB require the shard key in every query hitting a sharded collection. MongoDB only suggests to specify it.

Anyway, we have not yet found a way to manipulate the save operation so that is uses the shard key in the query section of the update command as well. Implementing a custom repository seems to be tricky since most classes we require to implement that are private or package private.

Does anyone have experience with this or is in a similar situation?